# Concatenate Checkbox Responses in Ecel

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have an excel form with set of 6 check boxes.  In VBA I know how to determine if the checkbox is checked or not, what I'm trying to do is reference them so I can concatenate that information into string to output to another cell.

For example if "Check Box 1" is checked I would like to output "Box1" in another cell, if both "Check Box 1" and "Check Box 2" is checked I would like to output "Box1, Box2" in a cell and so forth.

```
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
```

My overall goal is to create a sentence in another cell that will reference the checkboxes that are checked, so the user can copy and paste that information.

Comment: Use `WorksheetObj.CheckBoxes` Collection, `For Each` and `.Item(#)` works - hidden gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following macro will place the result in the active sheet, and in cell B2...

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim vCheckBoxNames As Variant
    Dim vCheckBoxName As Variant
    Dim sCheckBoxNames As String

    vCheckBoxNames = Array("Check Box 1", "Check Box 2", "Check Box 3", "Check Box 4", "Check Box 5", "Check Box 6")

    sCheckBoxNames = ""
    For Each vCheckBoxName In vCheckBoxNames
        If ActiveSheet.Shapes(vCheckBoxName).ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
            sCheckBoxNames = sCheckBoxNames & ", " & Mid(vCheckBoxName, 7)
        End If
    Next vCheckBoxName

    sCheckBoxNames = Mid(sCheckBoxNames, 3)

    Range("B2").Value = sCheckBoxNames

End Sub
```

Comment: Domenic, thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for!